# In this algorithm what is "b"?

Tags: notation

I'm trying to take an algorithm from this page: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171012154111/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65653.html) and convert it to working code. The step-by-step is as follows:

The following algorithm uses a similar (but slightly different) idea.
It uses two internal integer variables, m and r, which are not reset
at the beginning of the algorithm (in C, you would declare them
as "static").  Initially, m = 1 and r = 0.  We also have a parameter
N, which is a large integer such that 2N can still be represented
exactly in the computer.  As said before, n is the modulus of the
numbers you want to produce (they will be between 0 and (n - 1)), we
must have n < N, and we have a function NextBit() that returns a
truly random bit.

```
1. WHILE m < N DO r : = 2*r + NextBit(); m = 2*m; (r is a random
   variable of modulus m)
2. Divide m by n : m = n*q + b
3. IF r >= n*q, let m : = m - n*q, r : = r - n*q (r is still a random
   variable of modulus m), and go to step 1.
4. Otherwise, let x : = r mod n, r : = [r/n], and m : = q, and return 
   x.
```

However, I can't find any indication of what "b" is. Math expert, I am not.

Comment: It seems to be just the remainder of $m/n$. For example if $m=13$ and $n=3$, then $q=4$ and $b=1$.

Answer (score 3):

As noted by David Mitra in the comments. $b$ denotes the remainder. The [Division Algorithm theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) states that the division of integers produces a quotient and a remainder. That is, given a numerator $m$, and a denominator $n$, the division $m / n$ results in a quotient $q$ and a *remainder* $b$. Or, $$ m = qn + b. $$ In a programming setting, you can obtain $b$ using `rem` operation on $(m,n)$ if your language has one. Otherwise, you can always divide $m/n$, round down the results to get $q$, then $b$ is given by $b = m-qn$.